# Can I use word "electric" to say that some person is cool?

Tags: slang

urbandictionary says that "electric" is another way of saying "cool", "awesome", etc. But it also says that it can mean "Hitting it on really well with people, as if sparks are flying all about you". So questions:

1. Is this word much used & recognized in the first sense (cool, etc.) amongst English native speakers?
2. If I'm to say "You're electric" to a native speaker (especially a woman) without any specific context, will she likely interpret it in the first meaning or the second one (hitting it on well with people)?

Comment: No, I would take **electric** to mean the opposite of **cool** but it depends on what you mean by **cool** – relaxed, unemotional, hip, awseome etc.

Comment: @WeatherVane, by cool here I mean that I really like this person, their look, acting, etc.

Comment: So cool means hot?  (like bad means good?) (or no means yes?)

Comment: @WeatherVane, haha, kind of. I think you got the point. I'm really stuck on this person and trying to use some words to describe it. English is not my native language though, so I want to make sure there will be no ambiguity.

Comment: Well the early days of a relationship certainly *can* be electric. I have never used 'cool' in its slang sense. If I say "our relationship is cool" I mean that it has cooled off, or we barely tolerate each other – cool as in cold.

Comment: If you say "You're electric" to a native speaker (especially a woman) without any specific context, you'll probably get a puzzled look. An electric atmosphere, an electric personality are more idiomatic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I get the feeling that urbandictionary.com collects so many localised idioms from so many, often tiny, groups that their entries are almost useless. If they gave locations and dates for their entries their site would be a really valuable resource for people studying the development and usage of street speech. As it is it's about as much use as a chocolate teapot.

Comment: @BoldBen, Merriam-Webster also notes that it's "exciting as if by electric shock". Cambridge dictionary specifies it as "very exciting and producing strong feelings". Having read this, I suggested that this meaning could be extrapolated to a person. And there's song "She's electric" by Oasis, what's meant by electric there?

Comment: ... probably the meaning you want. But as song lyrics often include non-standard usages, they're equally often off-topic on ELU.

Answer (score 1):

Google defines:

> **Electric (adj):**
> having or producing a sudden sense of thrilling excitement.
>
> Example: the atmosphere was electric.

Similar:
tense
charged
electrifying
exciting
dramatic
exhilarating
intoxicating
dynamic
thrilling
stimulating
galvanizing
invigorating
animating
energizing
rousing
stirring
heady
moving
jolting
shocking
startling
knife-edge
explosive
volatile

+++++++

Most of the meanings are quite similar to one another and may have been used for decades.

John Travolta and Olivia Newton-John sang in the 1970s:

> 'Cause the power you're supplying
>
> It's electrifying (it's electrifying)'

Your proposed term 'You're electric' is hence well known and will likely be interpreted accordingly.